# Two columns from two different table without any join in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

[image]I want to know if we can display 2 columns from two different table with out creating any join.

Scenario is that I want to display values present in one column from table1 along with values in column two from Table 2. these two tables dont have any common column to have any kind of join.

Expected Output:

```
Column1 Column2
A        1
B        4
C        9
D        13
E
F
```

Comment: add your table structure and what you already tried for us to help you

Comment: `select product_key,promotion_key
from d_products,d_promotions`

Comment: show your table structure also

Comment: Table structure is very simple. I am not very sure if I understood your question on table structure properly.

Comment: SELECT * FROM d_products,d_promotions (see the results)

Comment: `SELECT * FROM d_products,d_promotions` is a join. However, the question is why joining is not allowed. Is this a school assignment or some kind of a clever challenge, or are you trying to solve an actual problem?

Comment: @FrancisSaul You will get a cross join that will look awful

Comment: @FrancisSaul  yes you are right. it created a cross join.

Comment: Do you need to do this directly in MySQL? No programming language? Its just not how a relational database was meant to work.

Comment: @davejal Image added.

Comment: @dan08 Yes. I need to do it directly in MYSQL. No programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I can get you started.

Create a `UNION` query where select the column you want and add a constant column that we'll use later.

```
SELECT column1 as col , 'T1' as tbl FROM table1;
UNION
SELECT other_column as col , 'T2' as tbl FROM table2;
```

This will give a table with 2 column

```
col | tbl
----------
 1  | T1
 2  | T1
 a  | T2
...
```

Then you can make a Pivot table query using 'tbl' as the headers. I'm terrible with Pivot tables, but some research might get you there. Or maybe some will edit this answer to add that information.

You may also be able to do something with subqueries to get the desired result.